# Stop camera from moving through meshes using Raycaster

Tags: camera, three.js

Following the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/api/core/Raycaster.html) it was easy to figure it out how to click on a mesh, but preventing the camera from going though a mesh not that easy. I need some guidelines.

**How can I stop the camera from moving through messes using [Raycaster](https://threejs.org/docs/api/core/Raycaster.html)?**

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/qexobuzoxi/edit?html,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>three.js webgl - interactive cubes</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body style="margin:0;overflow:hidden;">
  <div style="position:fixed;background:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);" onmouseout="new function(){controls=new function(){this.moveX=0;this.moveY=0;this.moveZ=0;this.rotateX=0;this.rotateY=0;};}"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onmousedown="new function(){controls.moveX=1;clickedIn=false;}" onmouseup="new function(){controls.moveX=0;}">Move Right</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" onmousedown="new function(){controls.moveX-=1;clickedIn=false;}" onmouseup="new function(){controls.moveX=0;}">Move Left</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" onmousedown="new function(){controls.moveY=-1;clickedIn=false;}" onmouseup="new function(){controls.moveY=0;}">Move Down</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" onmousedown="new function(){controls.moveY=1;clickedIn=false;}" onmouseup="new function(){controls.moveY=0;}">Move Up</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" onmousedown="new function(){controls.moveZ=1;clickedIn=false;}" onmouseup="new function(){controls.moveZ=0;}">Move Back</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" onmousedown="new function(){controls.moveZ=-1;clickedIn=false;}" onmouseup="new function(){controls.moveZ=0;}">Move Front</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" onmousedown="new function(){controls.rotateY=1;clickedIn=false;}" onmouseup="new function(){controls.rotateY=0;}">Rotate Right</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" onmousedown="new function(){controls.rotateY=-1;clickedIn=false;}" onmouseup="new function(){controls.rotateY=0;}">Rotate Left</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" onmousedown="new function(){controls.rotateX=1;clickedIn=false;}" onmouseup="new function(){controls.rotateX=0;}">Rotate Up</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" onmousedown="new function(){controls.rotateX=-1;clickedIn=false;}" onmouseup="new function(){controls.rotateX=0;}">Rotate Down</a></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/84/three.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var container;
    var camera, scene, raycaster, renderer;

    var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(),INTERSECTED=[],clickedIn/*bc starts like it was clicked*/=false,controls;

    var clock = new THREE.Clock();

    init();
    animate();

    function init() {

      controls = new function () {
        this.moveX = 0;
        this.moveY = 0;
        this.moveZ = 0;
        this.rotateX = 0;
        this.rotateY = 0;
      }

      container = document.createElement('div');
      document.body.appendChild(container);

      scene = new THREE.Scene();

      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);

      var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
      light.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
      scene.add(light);

      var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(20, 20, 20);

      for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

        var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: Math.random() * 0xffffff }));

        object.name = 'Index:' + i;
        object.userData.foo = 'foo';

        object.position.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 201) - 100;
        object.position.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 201) - 100;
        object.position.z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 201) - 100;

        object.rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
        object.rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
        object.rotation.z = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;

        object.scale.x = Math.random() + 0.5;
        object.scale.y = Math.random() + 0.5;
        object.scale.z = Math.random() + 0.5;

        scene.add(object);

      }


      raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setClearColor(0xf0f0f0);
      renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      renderer.sortObjects = false;
      container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      container.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        clickedIn = true;
        mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = - (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
      }, false);

      window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      }, false);

    }

    function animate() {

      requestAnimationFrame(animate);

      // raycaster
      raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
      var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);
      for (var i = 0; i < INTERSECTED.length; i++) {
        INTERSECTED[i].material.emissive.setHex(INTERSECTED[i].currentHex);
        INTERSECTED.splice(i, 1);
      }
      for (var i = 0; clickedIn && i < intersects.length; i++) {
        var length = INTERSECTED.push(intersects[0].object) - 1;
        INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED[length].material.emissive.getHex();
        INTERSECTED[length].material.emissive.setHex(0xff0000);
      }

      // move
      var delta = clock.getDelta(), step = 100, stepAngle = (Math.PI / 2);
      if (controls.moveX == 1) camera.translateX(step * delta);
      else if (controls.moveX == -1) camera.translateX(-step * delta);
      if (controls.moveY == 1) camera.translateY(step * delta);
      else if (controls.moveY == -1) camera.translateY(-step * delta);
      if (controls.moveZ == 1) camera.translateZ(step * delta);
      else if (controls.moveZ == -1) camera.translateZ(-step * delta);
      if (controls.rotateX == 1) camera.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), stepAngle * delta);
      if (controls.rotateX == -1) camera.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), -stepAngle * delta);
      if (controls.rotateY == 1) camera.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), stepAngle * delta);
      if (controls.rotateY == -1) camera.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), -stepAngle * delta);
      camera.updateMatrixWorld();

      // render
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you implementing a first-person camera or a third-person camera? Like,  should the camera stop in front of a mesh or just follow a freely moving target and avoid obstacles?

Comment: A first-person camera like I'm in a spaceship, flying through space and all I need is to not move through meshes I hit. I found Physijs, but I don't need something that complex, at least for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a *First-Person Camera*, I think that the right way to do that would be to use the bounding sphere of the camera and test it over each mesh of the scene, but if you really want to use a **raycaster** then I can think of 2 approaches :

### Approach 1

In your rendering loop :

- Update the position of your camera ;
- For each object in your scene :

  - Create a ray that goes from the camera to the mesh and starts slightly **before** the camera;
  - Cast the ray. If an intersection is found and lies before the camera (1), move the camera to the intersection point.

### Approach 2

In your rendering loop again :

- Update the position of your camera ;
- Create one ray that points towards the direction of the camera and starts slightly **before** the camera ;
- Create another ray that points in the opposite direction of the camera and starts slightly **after** the camera ;
- Cast the first ray. If an intersection is found and the intersection point lies before the camera (1) than move the camera to the intersection point ;
- If no intersection is found, cast the second ray. If an intersection is found and the intersection point lies after the camera (2) than move the camera to the intersection point.

[image: Algorithm cases]

The first algorithm is in *O(n)*, *n* being the number of objects in your scene whereas the second one is in *O(1)* but can be tricky with big meshes.

Comment: Thank you for your very expressive answer. I'm not attached to the raycaster approached if there is a better way. Can you also give some more details about using the "bounding sphere of the camera"? I'm still new to this.

Comment: Well in that case you'd have to detect collision between the bounding sphere of the camera and the objects of your scene and compute the collision response. Unfortunately, this is a really broad subject, and I can't use an SO answer to explain that.
You should try to use a physic engine, they should have solutions for that.
Additionally, there is a [very good paper](http://www.peroxide.dk/papers/collision/collision.pdf) about this.

Comment: I will also be interested in finding out the distance between the camera and the meshes around it. Also would like to highlight the first mesh that is in the front center of the camera regardless of its distance. Then adding that I would like to stop from moving through the mesh I hit my conclusion was that the reycaster is the way to go. Am I on the right track?

Comment: You can have the distance between the camera and the meshes with _approach 1_ given you normalize the direction of the ray.
Highlighting is done through trivial raycasting.
For collision, raycaster can work, try to change the space between the camera and the bound of the ray if you're experiencing problems.

Comment: This is how I highlight the mesh in the center of the camera and don't move with the camera through it using intersects[0].distance: https://jsbin.com/hatubesofe/edit?html,output. Can you show me some small code on how to create an array of rays and how to point them in different directions(I have front now, need also back, left, right, above, bellow. I already have initiated two Raycasters and I think there must be a way to pass an array, I saw some questions here with some snippets of code, but could't figure it out)?

Comment: Why do you need left, right, top, bottom rays? If it's not related to the question, please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).